# build failed in gradle

Tags: android, bash, android-gradle-plugin

I need to execute a bash script to change value in strings.xml in an android app when it builds. And here is the code I use in gradle script

```
    task packDex(type:Exec)  {

    commandLine 'sh /home/czhu/lokki/editxml.sh'
}

preBuild.dependsOn packDex
```

It failed and with only few words.

```
   :App:packDex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':App:packDex'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'sh /home/czhu/lokki/editxml.sh''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Through I searched a lot, but really have no idea how to fix. Please help me out.

Comment: Does it work if you change the command to `/bin/bash /home/czhu/lokki/editxml.sh`?

Comment: It still doesn't work when using /bin/bash. And the same error shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in stead:

```
executable '/home/czhu/lokki/editxml.sh'
```

Should work if you have a shebang in the script. 'commandLine' is the full command line. executable however should be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, the execultable works perfectly. But 'sh /home/czhu/lokki/editxml.sh' isn't the full command line?